# TextBox.IsEnabled binding works only once. Why?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm having problems with binding TextBox's `IsEnabled` property. I've seen some posts on this forum based on which the code below should work (at least this is what I thought).  However, when I run the app the call on the `IsNumberEnabled`  property executes only once - just before a corresponding view is loaded.
Can someone please give me a hand here.  Thanks.

xaml:

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNumberEnabled}" ... />
```

ModelView:

```
public bool IsNumberEnabled
{
    get { return ... condition ....; }  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `ModelView` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly.

When you change the value that impacts your `...condition...`, you need to raise `PropertyChanged` with `"IsNumberEnabled"` as the property name.  This will cause WPF to fetch and check the value again.

This often means that you'll have other properties which need to cascade and raise the `PropertyChanged` event more than once.  For example, if `IsNumberEnabled` depends on another property named `Foo`, then `Foo`'s property definition will look like:

```
public double Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set
    {
        if (foo != value)
        {
            foo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();  // Raise PropertyChanged event for "Foo"
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsNumberEnabled"); // Tell WPF to check this property too
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is it.  I did raise PropertyChanged event but on a wrong property.  Instead of IsNumberEnabled I was raising events on Number.  Thanks.